# "Considers" or "will consider" after "when"?

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, future

In this sentence:

> If he goes to therapy regularly and does not isolate himself, he will reach a moment when he **considers** with self-satisfaction that he is on the right path.

the word corrector suggested I use the present. I ignored that, since "when" here introduces a relative clause and not a time clause, and I wrote:

> If he goes to therapy regularly and does not isolate himself, he will reach a moment when he **will consider** with self-satisfaction that he is on the right path.

Is my intuition correct?

PS: This is a translation of a document that does not exist on the internet, so I cannot give a link to it.

Comment: No. You must use the present tense here. It's not optional. It doesn't make sense to say "when he will consider" in this context. The first is an example of using the simple [present in the future](https://www.theenglishbureau.com/blog/the-present-tense-for-the-future/#:~:text=%20HOW%20TO%20USE%20THE%20PRESENT%20TENSE%20FOR,verb%29%2C%20expected%20in%20%28%20time%29.%20Unlike...%20More%20). - see section 4: **In clauses**, the last example.

Comment: You can say "I know when he will arrive", but if we put "know" into the future this becomes "I will know when he arrives".  Obviously, both mean very different things.